# Change output type of windows form application visual studio professional 2010 trial c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to change the output type of a project created in VS from class to application but this option does not seem available as it cant be selected. Using c#

Anyone have any possible solutions?

Comment: Do you mean that when you go to properties of project and there on "Application" tab in "Output type" dropdown that item is locked?

Comment: Is your Class Library a Portable Class Library? That is the one you can't switch to an Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can change project type between class library, console application and windows application.

Based on your previous question you may be trying to change "web application" to "console application" which is not supported by VS. There is really no built-in way of making standalone executable from any of VS web site projects.

Comment: But I have already created an exe file using the same application. It seems to be when i add the database and another class the exe files turn into dll

Comment: @user3684874 - I seriously doubt it. exe projects do not magically change to any other type when you add classes/DB to them. You really should provide some information in your post...

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps create your class library project as a **Class Library (Portable)** project? If so, you cant just switch it. If this is the case, you'd need to create a new project and copy code over.

Your question is tagged VS 2010, but I think it is possible to install the platform kits to create Portable Class Libraries.